# ¿Por qué me sale "Violación de segmento (`core' generado)" en la ejecución de una función el recoger valores con scanf?

Tags: array, c, unix, makefile, make

En esta función, no me da errores de compilación pero en la ejecución me da un error como el que se ve en el titulo y se cierra el programa.
¿Qué debo cambiar para que funcione?
Gracias de antemano.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIMMAX 25

void introducirVectores(float *vector1, float *vector2, int *diml){
    int i;  

    do{
        printf("Dimensión de los vectores (entre 1 y %d)?: ", DIMMAX);
        scanf("%d", diml);
    }while (*diml <= 0 || *diml > DIMMAX); 

    puts("\nIntroduzca el primer vector:");
    for (i=0; i < (*diml); i++){
        printf("v1[%d]?: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &vector1[i]);
    }

    puts("\nIntroduzca el segundo vector:");
    for (i=0; i < *diml; i++){
        printf("v2[%d]?: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &vector2[i]);
    }
}
```

la funcion la llamo así:

```
float vector1[DIMMAX], vector2[DIMMAX];    
int diml;

introducirVectores(vector1, vector2, &diml);
```

Lo compilo con un makefile desde UNIX. Y me genera el core al probar con los datos:
-Número de elementos de los vectores 3.
-Valores: 1, 2, 3 en los dos vectores.

Dejo aqui la carpeta del proyecto: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11P2r_rDCn4-pQb-HlWMLPFyGOIyKXL0I/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hola! Podrías editar la pregunta y copiar el error tal cual lo ves? Por otro lado, compilé tu rutina con gcc e hice algunas pruebas y no me generó un core... Con que datos estás probando y bajo que casuistica te genera el core?

Comment: Hola he probado tu código y me funciona a la perfección.

Comment: Como lo compilas? a ver si  esta ahi el problema @Alexmaister

Comment: Puse el codigo todo en un fichero y le agregue a la funcion main la declaracion de las variables y la llamada a la funcion.  Lo compile sobre el terminal de Ubuntu con gcc main.c